# Terminology/naming of a default setup/environment class

Tags: php, frameworks

I'm working on *yet another* framework for PHP, and have run into a small dilemma. I'm currently working with the core modules, which all are supposed to work stand-alone but I'd like to have a class that creates a default setup or environment that can be used directly or extended by your app. So I need to find a good term/name for this class.

Current candidates:

- Engine
- Environment
- Main
- Base
- Init / Initializer
- Bootstrap
- App / **Application** (Chosen!)

The class resides in the `Core`-namespace, i.e. `Framework/Core/ClassName`.

Since I can't decide on which one to use I'm hoping you guys can help me pick the right one by shedding some more light on the terminologies of frameworks. I welcome new additions to the list above.

Just to make this as clear as possible, here's an example of how it's intended to be used:

```
use Framework/Core/ClassName as App;

// Create instance
$app = new App;
$app->run();

// Static initialization
App::run();
```

The above will setup a default environment with the most commonly used features of a modern framework. It will load config and url files from default locations and also setup default dispatch routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i usually try to use separate my Application and Config objects. Like

```
class MyApp extends App
     task specific methods

class MyConfig extends Config
     task specific settings

$app = new MyApp(new MyConfig);
$app->run();
```

The former can be called App(lication), Engine, Dispatcher, etc - something that emphasises it "actor" nature, the latter can be Environment, Config, Settings, Options etc.

Comment: Thanks for your input! This is more or less how it works, so what I need help deciding is what to name the base App class. Dispatcher is already in use by an URL dispatcher class for routing requests to their destination. Perhaps App or Application is a good idea, since it's located within the Core?

Comment: I'm going to go with Application. Makes the most sense since it's already inside the Core namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Just did a small  front-controler based app quite similar to your implementation. I named my initialisaation class a very unoriginal  "Init".  It's the class that loads settings, sets up error handling, logging and optionaly,  db connection and site-wide registry.

TlDR: Init is the name I retained for this when faced with same question.

Comment: Init is a good name, but I'd rather not use abbreviations so  I'd probably have to name it Initializer which is quite long and hard to type. I'll add it to the list of candidates however, thanks for your contribution!